# Why java Base64 runs different from eclipse and jar

Tags: java, base64

If I run this simple program that uses `java.util.Base64` within Eclipse it acts as expected, ie
if my char array contains:

```
char[] arr = { 54, 10, 145, 225, 242, 135, 6, 130, 20, 113, 109, 35, 33 };
```

my log output from Eclipse is:

```
Java Version: 17+35-LTS-2724
54,10,145,225,242,135,6,130,20,113,109,35,33,
Are equals !
54,10,145,225,242,135,6,130,20,113,109,35,33,
```

after `encodeToString()` and `decode()` it returns the same sequence of chars.
But if I bundle this (with maven) into a jar (next my pom.xml) and I run it from
command prompt with `java -jar` it converts some chars to (int)63 ?

My log output from jar execution is:

```
Java Version: 17+35-LTS-2724
54,10,145,225,242,135,6,130,20,113,109,35,33,
Strings are different !!!
54,10,63,225,242,63,6,63,20,113,109,35,33,
```

Here is my sample program

```java
public class TestB64 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestB64 b64 = new TestB64();
    b64.doTheJob();
  }

  public void doTheJob() {
    System.out.println("Java Version: " + System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));
    char[] arr = { 54, 10, 145, 225, 242, 135, 6, 130, 20, 113, 109, 35, 33 };
    printChArr(arr);
    String szFirst = new String(arr);
    Encoder enc = Base64.getEncoder();
    String coded = enc.encodeToString(szFirst.getBytes());

    Decoder dec = Base64.getDecoder();
    String szSecond = new String(dec.decode(coded.getBytes()));

    if ( !szFirst.equals(szSecond))
      System.err.println("Strings are different !!!");
    else
      System.out.println("Are equals !");
    printChArr(szSecond.toCharArray());
  }

  private void printChArr(char[] arr) {
    for (char cc : arr)
      System.out.printf("%d,", (int) cc);
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

and here my pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sm.clagenna</groupId>
    <artifactId>testb64</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Test Base64 with Maven</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.20</lombok.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <finalName>testb64</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <!-- arg -illegal-access=permit /arg -->
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>sm.clagenna.tb64.TestB64</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactid}</finalName>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>

                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                <path>
                                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                    <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                                </path>
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: The use of `getBytes()` is already a warning sign: it depends on the JVM's default charset which depends on the OS and environment (and which thus might be different for command line and IDE). Better use `getBytes(Charset)` and similar methods.

Comment: Great! This aspect dind't crossed my mind, thank !